# Add a 'break' in my php code

Tags: php, xml, foreach

Recently I am using php to deal with a xml file.

But I don't know how to add a 'break' in my code.

The link is : http://babystory.diandian.com/rss

I want to use php to get the article named '[x]快乐王子'.But "foreach()" give me the last article named '[1]狼和七只小山羊'.

I want to add a break in "foreach()" so that I can get the article I want.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://babystory.diandian.com/rss");

foreach($xml->children() as $child){}

foreach($child->children() as $child2)

foreach($child2->children() as $child3)
{
  $element = $child3->getName();
  if($element=='title')
  {
    echo "<h1>" . $child3 . "</h1>";
  }

  if($element=='description')
  {
    echo $child3;
  }
}
?>
```

Could you help me to edit my code.Thank you very much.

Comment: Simple use break statement. If you want break 2 cycles, use
        break 2;

Comment: When I run you code, I get all three stories -- not just one. And what are you trying to accomplish exactly? Do you want to exit parsing once you hit that story?

Comment: I want to get one story from the xml.If you open the xml,you can see there are three <item> elements.I want to get the first one not the last one.But now I don't know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the first item from your feed you don't need any foreach loops at all.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://babystory.diandian.com/rss");
$item = (array)$xml->channel->item[0]; // the article [x]快乐王子 array
```

Now `$item` is array of the first article information. So `$item['title']` is [x]快乐王子, `$item['link']` is http://babystory.diandian.com/post/2012-01-15/14770976, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much.You helped me to use array to solve the problem and also helped my to review the skill of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your last foreach....

i.e.
.....

```
foreach($child2->children() as $child3){
   if($child3->getName() == "title" && $child3 == "THE TITLE I WANT"){
       $saveItem = $child3;
       break 3;
   }
}
echo $saveItem;
```